# ～たところで - Even if ...?

Tags: grammar

[image: manga]

My question pertains to the 拒絶したところで quote in the third panel:

> 薄っぺらい道義心で本能を拒絶し**たところで**戦うお前は楽しそうだった
> お前の本能は血を求めてるんだよ神楽

The background is that the girl is from a tribe of bloodlusty mercenaries and has worked a few stints for this パンチパーマやくざ before deciding that she didn't want to have anything to do with mercenary work anymore and to turn over a new leaf.
I'm now trying to figure out the exact meaning of ～たところで here, as I've admittedly never come across it in this fashion. I assume the grammar used here is this one: https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2020/01/20/jlptn1-grammar-tatokorode/
but I'm not sure. That'd make the translation following: *Even with you rejecting (trying to reject?) your natural instincts with that thin line of moral sense of yours, you still seemed to enjoy yourself fighting. Your instincts are craving for blood, Kagura.*

I know that there are a few other ところs that could work in this fashion, e.g. 今食べ終わったところで、今腹いっぱいよ and 昨晩いい夢見てたんだけどちょうど面白いところで目を覚めちゃった but none of those make sense in this context. Am I right with my interpretation here? And if yes, is the 'tried to/attempted to' (even if you tried to reject your...) implied here? I'd expect something more along the lines of 拒絶しようとしたところで in that case but I don't exactly know about the specifics on how this grammar is usually used and interpreted.

As always any input is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Sorry for the lousy picture, if there's anything that needs to be cleared up, let me know!

Comment: It's technically ambiguous, but I agree with you that it is the JLPT N1 ～たところで. I'm not sure what is expected to answer your final question. It seems to me that what you described is all correct.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed your comment at all! At least we're on the same page here so I'll just go with the interpretation I have provided. Thank you for your input!